# What is a local device keychain?

Tags: keychain

I was reading the documentation for the [Connect Interface of Epic Online Services](https://dev.epicgames.com/docs/services/en-US/Interfaces/Connect/index.html#usingdeviceid) and under the section that discusses `Device ID`, it states that:

```
The EOS SDK stores the Device ID credential locally in the keychain of the currently logged
in user of the local device.
```

What I still don't understand is where this Device ID is actually stored. What is a device's local keychain?

Comment: Keychain is where IDs are stored so you can use it later.

Comment: @SaadAnees right but where would that keychain be? Say if I wanted to manually delete it when I removed a game that used it.

Comment: You can't manually delete by going to the location. You can use API from EOS SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You can't see the stored location but you can retrieve or store it with API from EOS SDK. `EOS_Auth_Logout` will create refresh token and save it in keychain. You can delete it by calling `EOS_Auth_DeletePersistentAuth` to explicitly remove any stored credentials in the local keychain for the user.

Read for docs [here](https://dev.epicgames.com/docs/services/en-US/Interfaces/Auth/index.html#persistinguserlogintoepicaccountoutsidetheepicgameslauncher).